# How to use format function inside google_logging_metric resource

Tags: terraform

My requirement is to variabilise cluster_name and namespace, and use in google_logging_metric resource

*my tfvars file :*

```
log_based_metrics = [
  {
    name = "name1",
    filter = "resource.type=\"k8s_pod\"\njsonPayload.kind=\"Event\"\nresource.labels.cluster_name=\"%s\"\njsonPayload.message:\"something\"\njsonPayload.involvedObject.namespace=\"%s\"",   << here I used %s for cluster name and namespace within filter>>
    metric_kind = "DELTA",
    value_type = "INT64"
  }
]
```

*My resource file :*

```
    resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric" {
      for_each = { for inst in var.log_based_metrics : inst.name => inst }
      name = each.value.name
      filter = "${format("${each.value.filter}",var.cluster_name,var.namespace)}"      
 *<< here when I am using each.value.filter inside format ,it is giving error , instead if I am replacing it with actual value from tfvars file it is not giving any error >>*    
      metric_descriptor {
        metric_kind = each.value.metric_kind
        value_type = each.value.value_type
        dynamic "labels" {
          for_each = each.value.labels
          content {
            key = labels.value["label_key"]
            value_type = labels.value["label_value_type"]
            description = labels.value["label_description"]
          }
        }
```

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on log_based_metrics.tf line 4, in resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric":
   4:   filter = "${format("${each.value.filter}",var.cluster_name,var.namespace)}"
    |----------------
    | var.cluster_name is "cluster-5"

Invalid value for "args" parameter: too many arguments; no verbs in format
string.
```

*when I use value of *each.value.filter* within format that is
"resource.type="k8s_pod"\njsonPayload.kind="Event"\nresource.labels.cluster_name="%s"\njsonPayload.message:"something"\njsonPayload.involvedObject.namespace="%s"
it was not giving any error
How can I use a variable from tfvars file in format function ??*

Comment: Can you clarify what is the issue with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin Provided the error.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? The error message indicates different code for `format`.

Comment: not sure why its giving that error , when I put the value of each.value.filter i

Comment: My point is that the error message shows that you code is `filter = "${format("${each.value.filter}",var.cluster_name,var.namespace)}"`. In the question you have different code. There are not quotations nor `$`. Thus what code are you actually using and why its different in the question?

Comment: sorry edited my question properly.

Comment: This code is still different then in the error message. Please make sure that your question actually represents your code. The same any error messages are based on the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
 filter = format(each.value.filter,var.cluster_name,var.namespace)
```

So basically like you had in the original question.

Comment: I am facing same above error with this syntax , I think format function is expecting a string something like "blahblah%s%s"      which means filter = format("blahblah%s%s",var.cluster_name,var.naemspace) is working  , but I want a variable in place of hardcoded string

Comment: @jyostnalalitha The syntax is correct. Please make sure you are using correct code. Because its confusing what is your actual code and what you use on SO.

Comment: @jyostnalalitha How did it go? Did you manage to verify what is your actual code and what you have in the question?

Comment: Thanks @Marcin the syntax is correct,the issue was there in variables file , one of my variable was not having %s which was causing issue .